# Is it a good practice to generate video thumbnails clientside using canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas, html5-canvas

I have been using an hidden canvas to generate video thumbnails on client side for quite some time (almost 2 years). While I don't have a lot of users (approximatively one hundred), I never had any issues with it.

On a website intended to be browsed on desktop, is there any red flags against this practice if I scale up? I would assume it is the opposite since it will spare a huge amount of server resources.

Comment: Is the video already client side (ie they're uploading it), or are you displaying a thumbnail of something on the server?

Comment: In my opinion, you don't spare resources: All videos have to be downloaded by every client just to render the thumbnail. Contrary: When you render the thumbnail server-side on upload, you can provide just an image to all clients and only need to provide the video when they start playback.

Comment: @JamesThorpe right now, I only make some when they play it. It means that until it is played for the first time, there is no thumbnail. Eventually, I'll make the main ones during the upload. Since I feature video pseudo-editing, I will still need to create thumbnails on already uploaded videos (i.e. the video chunk tihumbnail), as I already do.

Comment: @psi I do not store anything on the server. I use certificates and S3 to separate data from code (see https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot). Of course, the thumbnail is generated only if it is missing. If not, the thumnnail generated by the first client who watched the video will be provided.